# How can I make one of the fields in admin.TabularInline conditional?

Tags: python, django, if-statement, admin, inline

Is there a way how can I make one of the fields in `admin.TabularInline` conditional?

for example

```
class ParameterInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = ParameterForm
    fields = ["ParameterA", "ParameterB"]
```

What if I wanted to display the `ParameterB` only if something else was set to, for example, `True`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where would you get the `True` value?

Comment: So far I have come up with an idea which is to create two inlines and using the following method try to choose the appropriate one but it is not working yet.

    `def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=object):
        if obj is not None:
            hasattr(obj, "UnitId")
            self.inlines.remove(ParameterInlineA)
            return [inline(self.model, self.admin_site) for inline in self.inlines]
        else:
            self.inlines.remove(ParameterInlineA)
            return [inline(self.model, self.admin_site) for inline in self.inlines]`

Comment: Apologies for how it looks like, did not make it to edit it within the 5 mins limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the `get_fields` method:

```
class ParameterInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = ParameterForm
    fields = ["ParameterA"]
    
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(ParameterInline, self).get_fields(request=request, obj=obj)
        if True:
            return fields + ['ParameterB']
        return fields
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I did, of course, upvote but my reputation isn"t  sufficient to show the change publically,.. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I managed to work around it, although I have the feeling that this is not the most effective way.

I have two such inlines now with one difference

```
class ParameterInlineA(admin.TabularInline):
    form = ParameterForm
    fields = ["ParameterA", "ParameterB"]

class ParameterInlineB(admin.TabularInline):
    form = ParameterForm
    fields = ["ParameterA"]
```

and the following function to dynamically swap between entire inlines;

```
def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=object):
    inliness = self.inlines
    if obj is not None:
        inlines = inliness
        obj = <registeredModel>.objects.get(id = obj.id)
        if obj.<attributeToSortBy> is None:
            inlines.remove(ParameterInlineA)
            inlines.append(ParameterInlineB)
            return [inline(self.model, self.admin_site) for inline in inlines]
        else:
            inlines.append(ParameterInlineA)
            inlines.remove(ParameterInlineB)
            return [inline(self.model, self.admin_site) for inline in inlines]
```